# Facebook iOS SDK - fetching user albums

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK in my iPhone app. I want to find the user's Facebook profile photos, for that I am using the below code:

```
-(IBAction)FacebookLogin:(id)sender{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

        [self findAlbums];
    } else {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_photos",
                                nil];

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState status,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                                      if (error) {


                                      } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {

                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
                                           ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                               if (!error) {
                                                   [self findAlbums];

                                               }
                                           }];
                                      }
                                  }];
    }
}

-(void)findAlbums {
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                              NSLog(@"result::%@",result);
                          }];

}
```

> Out put ----   data =     ( );

This does not give any albums in data. The Facebook user logged in have many albums and photos in his profile. Why this happens?

Comment: try it first on graph api explorer. may be there you will find  the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

just change the code in find albums to :

```
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/albums"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
                              NSLog(@"user events: %@", result);
                              NSArray *feed =[result objectForKey:@"data"];

                              for (NSDictionary *dict in feed) {

                                  NSLog(@"first %@",dict);

                              }
                          } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                              // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                              NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
                          }
 }];
```

Comment: this is same... Out put ---- data = ( );
I think it is still a bug on the current fbsdk given this permisison "user_photos"

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the Facebook credentials(i.e facebook account) you're using to the Facebook developer account settings(i.e as admin or developer) , only then you can access the album's photos through your code